Visual Studio 2022 with publish Docker and local NuGets
my situation is that I have a solution with 3 Projects:
A: Starter as Console App
B: Starter as Webservice aspnet.core und swagger should run later within a docker image
C: Modul Lib (this one requires a bunch of NuGets that where hosted on my dev machine and on two unc paths within the network)
Any Build of A + C works fine
B+C against local Docker:

Any buildtype like DEBUG to container works fine. Build, create and start docker no issue
Any buildtype like RELEASE fails against docker, but IIS, http works fine.
B+C with publish as docker:
Option a SDK: Build run through without any problem, but don't know where the image is. In Docker for Windows it don't appears nor publish target
Option b Docker: Build fails, can't find the mentioned local NuGet.

Also facing the problem that VS don't copy the context/meta stuff from user to the build folder. I copy that manulley when the message appears, then its gone.
I tried every approch I found e.g. copying the nuget.config to the image (as lower case) then bind it by --configfile behind RUN dotnet restore xxx.csproj. It looks like that the build runs within the container, that would explain NU1102,1101 etc.
I have 2 ideas:
a) create a app that does similare to dotnet restore and parses the .csproj's for local nuget and copy them to folders and copy them to the container before build
b) create a app to publish my local nuget to a devops nuget feed and run the --configfile with the nuget.org and my devops feed
Some had a solution for that problem or other approches??
kind regards :)
UPDATE:
In the mean time got managed to get it working. It was a bunch of changes. The 2 main problems were:
a) Nuget package's (not code signed) from local source, can't be copied to container on RELEASE builds (for which reason ever .. ) so I tried a few things and got it working by using DevOps as Nuget source for Release Builds only.
b) Had to edit the DOCKERFILE: copy the nuget.config to the container in the apps root folder, copy some other stuff from outside before restore.
Now I am able to push it to local docker registry and use it from other locations.
The meta folder thing were fix in 17.10.3+ release .. so a update resolved that.
Thanks guys

The not copying the nuget.config file is a bug and is probably the same issue as https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/439

If you're having issues with NuGets in Docker then using the SDK to build the image is usually your best bet. In Visual Studio 17.11 there are two ways to leverage the SDK's support for building images:
At Debug time:
Right-click on the project->Add->Docker support... then choose "Container Build Type": ".NET SDK"

This creates a launch profile for publishing an image using the SDK to the local store and running it locally.
At Publish time:

Right-click on the project->Publish
Pick "Docker Container Registry"
Choose the Registry Type and Registry you'll publish to
Choose ".NET SDK"


This creates a Publish Profile that builds an image using the .NET SDK and publishes it to the specified registry.
